# Launch statistics by year

Tags: discussion

I am curious about such yearly space launch numbers:

- space launches
- sounding rockets space launches
- ICBM space launches
- space launches excluding sounding rockets and ICBM
- orbital launches (might be same as satellite launches, not sure though)
- satellite launches
- satellites launched (one launch can put 10 satellites in orbit so this number is greater than the previous one)
- space launches leaving orbit (e.g. Mars launches)

Also CubeSat launches and and active or in orbit at the year end.

Some numbers can be gathered with the scripts like those at the accepted answer here:

[What was the most busy week in space launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/45696/what-was-the-most-busy-week-in-space-launches)

Is it ok to ask such things? If yes then which ones of them and each one in a separate question or all in a single question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the fate of this question of yours is a bad sign:

[Number of space launches by year until 2020](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45868/58)

I think it is unlikely that a question of this broad of a scope will be well received here. You might be better off asking for resources about how to find this information, though I would caution you that resource requests themselves have to be very carefully phrased to avoid being closed for being open-ended lists.

Comment: I think it is really interesting to see how many satellites were in orbit and how many of them were active at the end of each year. A question for asking resources for such numbers would be ok?

Comment: @JoeJobs Yes, I think so. Maybe try out the wording in the answer space here, and we can give you feedback on the best way to word it to avoid closure on the main site.

Comment: Thanks I opened an answer containing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in finding information on how many satellites were in orbit and how many of them were active at the end of each year (for all years of space activity).

What are the standard resource(s) for obtaining this data? Preferably web resources.

Comment: I proposed a wording I think would be more effective. Let me know what you think.

Comment: And for the title, I would suggest "What are the standard resources for numbers of all orbiting as well as specifically active satellites by year?"

Comment: That's much better wording, thanks! How about asking for the same numbers for Cubesats? If that would be ok then better in a separate question?

Comment: Hmm, that's a tough call. Maybe add it as a bonus in this question. Something like: "If the resources also separate out the number of Cubesats, that would be great!" Then if you don't end up getting an answer that includes that, you could ask another question and you would have sufficient justification (you could point to the fact that your previous question focused on more general resources didn't get any results specific to Cubesat). The reason I say to add it as a bonus is that way you avoid the impression you're asking for too much.

Comment: Thanks. How about putting a bounty and reward it for the answer to the bonus question? :)

Comment: I think that would be fine.